# What are the compiler, CLR or CPU optimizations to be aware of when working with threads and non-blocking synchronization?

Tags: .net, synchronization, clr, multithreading, compiler-optimization

As the title says, what are the compiler, CLR or CPU optimizations to be aware of when working with threads and non-blocking synchronization?

I have read a little about the reordering of instructions to improve efficiency that could break things, and caching optimizations that will result in variables not being visible to other threads right away [[0]](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx), but are there other (I sure there are) that I need to be aware of?

Any links to recommended reading/blogs/articles/etc will be much appreciated.

Thanks, Egil.

**Update:** Thanks to Jons link to Joe Duffy's blog post I found a lot more great information that I thought I would share with you guys:

- The primary article that many point to is [Understand the Impact of Low-Lock Techniques in Multithreaded Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163715.aspx) by Vance Morrison.
- [What Every Dev Must Know About Multithreaded Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163744.aspx), also by Vance Morrison, is a very good fresher up for those of us who do not dabble in multithreaded applications daily.
- Joe Duffy's [9 Reusable Parallel Data Structures and Algorithms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163427.aspx) is also a great read.
- More of the same from Jeffrey Richter in his [Concurrent Affairs column Performance-Conscious Thread Synchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163726.aspx). His implementation of a SpinWaitLock is pretty nice.
- In general, the [Concurrency Affairs columns over at MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee532402.aspx?sdmr=concurrentaffairs&sdmi=columns) are very recommendable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know about the .NET memory model, basically. Ignore what optimisations are currently performed - code to the model.

I would recommend [this blog post](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2007/11/10/CLR20MemoryModel.aspx) by Joe Duffy as a good starting point.

I'd also recommend that you *don't* roll your own lock-free code. It's simply too hard for mortals, IMO. Use frameworks like Parallel Extensions (in .NET 4.0) which do the right thing for you.

Answer (score 1):

Joe Duffy has an excellent book called "[Concurrent Programming on Windows](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/books/winconc/winconc_book_resources.html)" that I definitely recommend reading if you're interested in concurrency on Windows (including lock free programming).